# How do i know if the ssd i want to buy is compatible with my motherboard?

Tags: ssd, motherboard, upgrade, desktop, compatibility

I have an Asus P8H61-MX USB3 and since i've had my pc for a couple of years now, i find myself in need of an upgrade. I have already found a RAM and a graphics card, but i cant figure out how to check the compatibility of the ssd i want to buy (Samsung 860 Evo 500GB) is compatible with my motherboard. Any thoughts?

Answer (score 1):

Your [motherboard](https://www.asus.com/Motherboards/P8H61MX/specifications/) only supports "*standard*" SATA connections - i.e: it doesn't have an mSATA or M.2 socket on it.

The [Samsung 860 EVO](https://www.samsung.com/semiconductor/minisite/ssd/product/consumer/860evo/) comes in one of three form factors:

- 2.5"
- mSATA
- M.2

[image: 860 EVO Form Factors, annotated]

As your motherboard doesn't support anything other than "*standard*" SATA, you should purchase the 2.5" model, and connect it accordingly.